# Kentico 9 Hierarchical Transformation Page Types Not Working

Tags: transformation, kentico

I am using Hierarchical transformations in a Hierarchical viewer.  In an attempt to get the Current item transformation to work properly I read I need to assign page type(s).  However, I've found that when I apply page types - even to the regular Item transformation - the transformations no longer get applied, even if I apply every single available page type.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to assign a page type specifically for it.  I'm guessing the problem is the selected page or current page is probably a level further down in the hierarchy OR you haven't applied the same markup as in your other transformation.  What I typically do for a more difficult hierarchy is create some generic transformations and simply place some static text inside it like so:

```
<ul> <!-- level 0 header -->
  <li><%# Eval("DocumentName") %> <!-- level 0 item -->
  <li><%# Eval("DocumentName") %> <!-- level 0 current item -->
  <ul> <!-- level 1 header -->
    <li><%# Eval("DocumentName") %> <!-- level 1 item -->
    <li><%# Eval("DocumentName") %> <!-- level 1 current item -->
...
```

Doing this allows you to see where things will be rendered.

Now lets say the difference between level 1 item transformation and level 1 current item transformation is a simple CSS class change.  Your current transformation needs to have the same code as your item transformation, PLUS the new CSS class.  Like so:

**Item Transformation**

```
<li><a href="#">Click Me</a></li>
```

**Current Item Transformation**

```
<li><a class="selected" href="#">Click Me</a></li>
```

This is a very common problem with `first` and `last` transformations, you need to apply that full markup in order for it to properly render.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the page types selected in the web part in page types? Or are you using a datasource?

If you are using a datasource, you have to include the classname in the results.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the people who have commented so far. Testing it out with sample HTML will make sure you are calling the right transformation at the right point in the hierarchy.

Is anything coming out on the transformation results?

If nothing is, it might also be worth checking if you are adding specific columns into the web part settings. Remove them first and get the transformation working and then add them in after.

Also remember the setting for 'Hierarchical display mode:', make sure this is inner. And make sure your using '' as this will help too.